# Where can I get authentic Info about the Caliphates of Abu Bakr, Umar, Uthman and Ali?

Tags: history, authenticity, ali, khilafah

We have sahih hadiths to learn authentic info about the life of the prophet, do we have something equivalent in authority and reliability for those four caliphs ?

Comment: You may find some of it quoted in hadith compilations.

Comment: I recommend the 4 books of Ali Muhammad El-Salaby, he wrote about each Caliph with all details about their lives, especially the 4th book of Ali [RA].

Answer (score 0):

ou can search the list of history books related to the events and history after the death of the Prophet. The books I introduce Most of them are Arabic, and I used the sources of articles written about the early caliphs.

-Ibn Hisham, Al-Sira Al-Nabawiyyah, published by Mustafa Saqqa, Ibrahim Abyari, and Abdul Hafiz Shalabi, Cairo 1355/1936

- Hassan Ibrahim Hassan, History of Islam: Political, Religious, Cultural and Social, Vol. 1, Cairo 1964
- Amini Abdul Hussein, Al-Ghadir in the Book of Sunnah and Literature, vol. 8, Beirut 1387/1967.
- Siouti Abdul Rahman Ibn Abi Bakr, History of the Caliphs, published by Mohammad Mohiuddin Abdul Hamid, Cairo, 1378/1959;
- Majlisi, Mohammad Abdul Qadir Khrisat, "Al-Qata'i Fi Sadr al-Islam: The Age of the Prophet and the Righteous Caliphs", Historical Studies, pp. 27 and 28.
- Ibn Athir, Ali Ibn Muhammad, Al-Kamil Fi Al-Tarikh, Beirut, 1385-1386 / 1965-1966, offset printing 1399-1402 / 1979-1982
- Ibn Abi al-Hadid, Sharh Nahj al-Balaghah, published by Muhammad Abu al-Fadl Ibrahim, Cairo, 1387-1385 / 1965-1967
- Ibn Babavieh, Kamal al-Din and all the blessings, published by Ali Akbar Ghaffari, Qom, 1984.

https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%AE%D9%84%D9%81%D8%A7%DB%8C_%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%86#cite_note-23

Answer (score -1):

about Ali peace on him:
Hadith of the day of the house(یوم الدار):
.... Ali (as), who was the youngest of all, said: O Prophet of God! I will help you. The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: This is my brother, guardian, and caliph among you, so listen to him and obey.
(History of Nations and Kings, Muhammad bin Jarir al-Tabari, Beirut, Dar Dimas al-Hadith, vol. 2, p. 217)
Aye Velayat(ولایت) IN Qoran:
انما ولیکم الله و رسوله و الذین آمنوا الذین یقیمون الصلاه و یوتون الزکاه و هم رکعون
Your guardian is God and His Messenger and those who believe, those who establish prayer and pay zakat while they are bowing.

and You can also search for the following in this case:
IN Qoran: Ayeh Tabligh(آیه تبلیغ), Ayeh olol'amr(آیه اولی الامر)
IN Hadith: Hadith Manzelat(منزلت), (ثقلین), Hadith Qadir(غدیر), Hadith Jaber(جابر بن عبدالله انصاری)